# How to listen to a global event triggered by WebCam Error: NotAllowedError

Tags: javascript, webrtc, ar.js

I'm using ar.js which uses the users webcam and issues a permission prompt to do so. What I want is to listen to a global event triggered by this dialogue if the user either allows or denies access to the webcam or has done so previously.

I've tried with global listeners like:

```
 document.documentElement.addEventListener("error", e=>{console.log("GOT ERROR : ", e)})
 window.addEventListener("error", e=>{console.log("GOT ERROR : ", e)});
```

[WebRTC errors on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/error) references only global error events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know `ar.js` events, and can't answer whether it has some direct way to observe this.

If you're asking for a way to hack around it, then there's no such global event in browsers. `NotAllowedError` is from calling `await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()`.

But if you know approximately when it's prompting the user, then you can do a parallel request, [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/Lt3xavuc/):

```
// library
(async () => {
  video.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});
})();

// us
(async () => {
  try {
    await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});
    console.log("GOT CAM");
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("GOT ERROR : " + e);
  }
})();
```

This should give you the notification you want without causing a second user prompt.

It works because the spec mandates that [getUserMedia](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/getusermedia.html#dom-mediadevices-getusermedia) must succeed without prompting the user again if the page already has a camera stream.

If you don't know when it'll prompt, then you'd need to override the `getUserMedia` method on the `navigator.mediaDevices` object. Various libraries like [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtcHacks/adapter) do this successfully, if you need an example.

Comment: This works!
I tested the snippet placing it directly after the ar.js include in head and it fires when the permissions prompt appears:
`...
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.6.2/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
<script>
      (async ()=> {
        try {
          await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});
          console.log("GOT CAM");
        } catch (e) {
          console.log("GOT ERROR : " + e);
        }
      })();
    </script>
</head>`
Placed further down in the code it will execute when the  dialogue is pressed.